# $(f_n)$ is bounded and $f_n\to f$ uniformly, show that $f$ is bounded.

Tags: convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, proof-writing, uniform-convergence

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and suppose $(f_n)$ is a bounded sequence of functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (here bounded means there exist a real number $M$ such that $|f_n(x)|\leq M$ for all $x\in X$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$). Suppose that $f_n\to f$ uniformly. Prove that $f$ is bounded.

I tried using two different approaches:

1. Using the triangle inqeuality (while skipping some details): $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ and $f_n(x)-f(x)|\leq|f_n(x)|+|f(x)|\leq M+?$ then I'm not sure how to show that $|f(x)|$ is bounded.
2. Suppose the contrary that $f$ is unbounded. Then there is an $x'\in X$ such that $f_n(x')\nrightarrow f(x')$ as $n\to\infty$ and it is a contradiction. But I'm not sure whether my working is correct? And I'm not sure how to write it more properly?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can't you just pass to the limit in the inequality $|f_n(x)|\le M$?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro. I am not sure, is there such a theorem?

Comment: Well, yes, it is a theorem that any inequality $a_n\le M$ extends to $a\le M$ if $a_n\to a$. It is one of the basic facts in analysis. The proof is easy: fix $\epsilon$, then for sufficiently big $n$ one has $a\le a_n+\epsilon\le M+\epsilon$. Etc, etc ...

Comment: If e.g. $f(x)>M$ then also $f_n(x)>M$ for $n$ large enough. So you are allowed to conclude that $f(x)\leq M$. Same for $f(x)\geq-M$. You do not need uniformity of convergence.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$
\lvert f(x) \rvert \leq \lvert f(x)-f_N(x) \rvert + \lvert f_N(x) \rvert < 1+M
$$
where $N$ is so large that $\lvert f(x)-f_N(x) \rvert < 1$ for all $x \in X$.